# Retrieve ID of Resource Created in Terraform Module

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-modules

This is the Error I am getting when trying to retrieve the IDs of subnets made via a module in Terraform:

```
 Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on outputs.tf line 3, in output "one_azure_subnet_id":
│    3:     for id in keys(var.subnets) : id => module.Subnet.azure_subnet_id[id]
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.Subnet is object with 3 attributes
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "azure_subnet_id".
```

I have made a Subnet Module in Terraform with this structure

```
Subnet/
┣ main.tf
┣ outputs.tf
┗ variables.tf
```

In the Subnet Module I have this code in Main.tf

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet_module" {
  name                 = var.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = var.address_prefixes
}
```

In outputs.tf

```
output "azure_subnet_id" {
  value = azurerm_subnet.subnet_module[*].id
  description = "Lists the ID's of the subnets"
}
```

In Variables.tf

```
variable "subnet_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "address_prefixes" {
  type = list(string)
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Resource Group Name"
}

variable "vnet_name" {
  type = string
  description = "vnet name"
}
```

This is how I am calling the Subnet module in my main project area:

```
module "Subnet" {
  source               = "./Modules/Subnet"
  for_each             = var.subnets
  subnet_name          = each.value["name"]
  address_prefixes     = each.value["address_prefixes"]
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  vnet_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
}
```

This is the Subnet Variable I am passing in.

```
subnets = {
  subnet_1 = {
    name             = "dev-virtual-subnet"
    address_prefixes = ["10.13.1.0/24"]
  }
  subnet_2 = {
    name             = "test-virtual-subnet"
    address_prefixes = ["10.13.2.0/24"]
  }
  subnet_3 = {
    name             = "staging-virtual-subnet"
    address_prefixes = ["10.13.3.0/24"]
  }
}
```

This is the Outputs.tf file in my main area to retrieve the ID of subnets made with the module:

```
output "onefms_azure_subnet_id" {
  value = {
    for id in keys(var.subnets) : id => module.Subnet.azure_subnet_id[id]
  }
  description = "Lists the ID's of the subnets"
}
```

Comment: Would `module.Subnet[id].azure_subnet_id` work?

Comment: That actually worked thank you!! I dont know why I did not see that of course.

Answer (score 0):

Received the same error in my case
When I used

```
output "onefms_azure_subnet_id" {
  value = {
    for id in keys(var.subnets) : id => module.subnet.azure_subnet_id[id]
  }
}
```

or

```
output "onefms_azure_subnet_id" {
  value = {
    for id in keys(var.subnets) : id => azurerm_subnet.subnet.azure_subnet_id[id]
  }
}
```

│ Error:

```
 Unsupported attribute
│
│  199:     for id in keys(var.subnets) : id => azurerm_subnet.subnet[*].azure_subnet_id
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "azure_subnet_id".
```

[image]

[image]

As suggested by *@marko E* comment.  I tried to retreive all the subnets with the following command azurerm_subnet.subnet[*] to get all subnet details.

And it worked.

```
output "onefms_azure_subnet_id" {
  value = {
    for id in keys(var.subnets) : id => azurerm_subnet.subnet[*]
  }
  description = "Lists the ID's of the subnets"
}
```

Variable.tf:

```
variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    name             = string
    address_prefixes = list(string)
  }))
default = {
    
  subnet_1 = {
    name             = "dev-virtual-subnet"
    address_prefixes = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  }
  subnet_2 = {
    name             = "test-virtual-subnet"
    address_prefixes = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
  }
  subnet_3 = {
    name             = "staging-virtual-subnet"
    address_prefixes = ["10.0.3.0/24"]
  }
}
}
```

[image]